# VB6 - A foxpro 2.6 no isam error on XP

Tags: vb6, foxpro, isam

The boss handed me some rather ancient legacy code, all done in VB6. After installing Visual Studio 6 and a few other things, I'm finally able to open the project and actually compile/run it. My new problem comes from this line of code:

```
Set db = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase(ThePath$, False, ReadOnlyFlag, "FoxPro 2.6;")
```

I get the error "Cannot find installable ISAM"

I'm not sure what I'm missing. I've done some searching and I have things like MSJET35.DLL in system32 and the registry. Access is installed (I tried it with both Access 2002 and 2003). I would expect this to be a problem with Windows 7 or Vista, but this is in XP, service pack 3.

Any thoughts anyone?

Comment: [First Google result](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/235357/en-us).

Comment: I never installed Visual Foxpro so it couldn't have overwritten it

Comment: Please actually read the article, not just the header.

Comment: I did read the article, and what it wants me to do strikes me as this is a different issue from the one I'm having. I'm not using the driver they're referring to, and other machines here, with the same settings, run it fine.

Comment: They are saying in the article that driver for Foxpro 2.X has been deprecated and, as of MDAC 2.1, is no longer available. Starting from MDAC 2.1, a substitute driver must be used. You apparently are trying to use a system DSN that refers to this deprecated driver. If you are not actually using this driver, then what does that `"FoxPro 2.6;"` bit mean? Do the other machines have DSNs that you don't?

Comment: Honestly I have no idea, but there are other similar machines with things like Office 2000 (things mentioned in the article that should override the driver), but the software runs for them. They're using the same code with "FoxPro 2.6;" so I don't know what the difference is between their machine and mine. The only suggestion I was given by the boss was to look in administrator settings and see what driver is associated with reading dBase files. He said it should be one that uses Access, but I don't even see that on the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FoxPro drivers are not included in MDAC 2.6 and beyond. Download the appropriate install for either ODBC or OLEDB

[FoxPro ODBC drivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vfoxpro/bb190233)
[FoxPro OLEDB drivers](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14839)

Answer (score 1):

`FoxPro 2.6` requires a dll called `msxbse35.dll`

Copy it into your system32 directory and run `regsvr32 msxbse35.dll` to register.
Your program will then run fine on that computer.