# Cannot find installable ISAM

Tags: vb6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [VB6 - A foxpro 2.6 no isam error on XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904001/vb6-a-foxpro-2-6-no-isam-error-on-xp)

I am running below code on VB6 on Windows 7. 
But it prompt error that `Cannot find installable ISAM`.
Do you know how to solve it?

```
Set dbMaster = OpenDatabase(App.Path, False, False, "FoxPro 2.6")
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904001/vb6-a-foxpro-2-6-no-isam-error-on-xp